# html2canvas not downloading the image with firefox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i'm using html2canvas , and i try to download the div as picture

it's work fine on google chrome but in fire fox it's not

this is my code

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#save_image_locally').click(function(){
      html2canvas([document.getElementById('#mydiv')],
      {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          a.download = 'somefilename.jpg';
          a.click();
        }
      });
});
  </script>
```

Comment: This is not sufficient information to give you an answer. You need to provide a full page (http://www.sscce.org/, your page does is not self-contained (not complete), although it is short) so we can download and test (as what you gave us doesn't even work in Chrome from our point of view.) **and/or** you need to let us know what errors are being generated in the Console. The Console is usually available in the F12 tools.

Comment: Are you getting index size error???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/obkm27v5/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#save_image_locally').click(function(){
        html2canvas([document.getElementById('mydiv')],
        {
          onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var a = $("<a>").attr("href", canvas.toDataURL('image/png'))
            .attr("download", "output.png")
            .appendTo("body");
            a[0].click();
            a.remove();
          }
        });
  });
```

You have to add the anchor tag to the DOM before clicking. There was also a wrong id in your canvas selector

Comment: It works. thanks. However html2canvas is not able to give me image from highcharts. I want to take image from highcarts graphs on all the browsers. Its working for chrome only.